# "No such file:" error in jenkins when integrating with Maven build

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I have recently started using Jenkins as a CI tool for my Maven Selenium automation project.

The path of my local eclipse workspace is:

```
/media/user/Data/Automation_Scripts
```

and the complete path of the `pom.xml` file used to execute the project is:

```
/media/user/Data/Automation_Scripts/[project_name]/pom.xml
```

Now, I have installed Jenkins and added a Maven project to it. When I try to enter the path my project's `pom.xml` file in the 'Root POM' text field under 'Build' I get following error:

```
No such file: ‘/media/user/Data/Automation_Scripts/test/pom.xml’
```

[image: error_message_section]

Whereas if I navigate to the same path the `pom.xml` file is present. When I build the Maven project in Jenkins, following error is shown:

```
Started by user Test Building in workspace
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST/workspace Parsing POMs ERROR: No such file
/media/user/Data/Automation_Scripts/test/pom.xml Perhaps you need to
specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Update:**

I created a pom.xml file in my jenkins workspace which is located at:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST/workspace
```

In this pom file have given path of my actual pom.xml (which is located in another folder) in the following way:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name>Maven Default Project</name>
<artifactId>jenkins_test</artifactId>  

<parent>
<groupId>ca.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven_test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>/media/user/Data/Automation_Scripts/test/pom.xml</relativePath>
 </parent>
</project>
```

Still I am getting following error now:

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST/workspace
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact ca.test:maven_test:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 9

at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:361)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:331)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1301)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1098)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:960)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:679)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I guess there is something wrong with the relative path. Can you tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing relative path instead of actual absolute path.
By default jenkins job considers path as workspace path.
Make pom.xml available in workspace of the job and provide path as just file name I.e pom.xml

Comment: Hi @Anand, I have added the pom file in my jenkins workspace and and changed path as just file name in jenkins job, but still I'm getting another error. Please refer the edited posted above. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume the path you have given for pom.xml is your Parent Project and you are using in your sub Project.  If your project resides in some repository you can try checking out repository in build job. You can clone both the repositories Parent as well as your sub project. and provide relative path in pom.xml of your child project. (../PARENT/pom.xml)

Comment: what do you mean by parent project? my jenkins worksapce is at: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST/workspace and the path of the pom.xml (which I use to run eclipse project) is at: /media/user/Data/Automation_Scripts/test/pom.xml

Comment: I did'nt understand what you meant by: " You can clone both the repositories Parent as well as your sub project. and provide relative path in pom.xml of your child project. (../PARENT/pom.xml) "

Comment: Why can't you clone(that is make your project folder available in your Jenkins workspace).  Normally Jenkins jobs are created to clone the code from remote location and build using build tool maven in your case.